# How can I make it so when I click the up or down button, the number increases or decreases

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a vote feature so when someone clicks the up arrow, the number increases, and when someone clicks the down arrow, the number decreases.

Here's my html and css

```css
.upVote {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
}

.downVote {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  padding-bottom: -50;
}
```

```html
<p>how do you vote?</p>
<button class="upVote">></button>
<span>0</span>
<button class="downVote">></button>
```

Comment: What number??...

Comment: You need to use javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<style>
  .upVote {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    padding-bottom: -50;
  }
  
  .downVote {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
  }
</style>
<script>
  function upVoteFunction() {
    var current = parseInt(document.getElementById("vote").innerHTML);
    document.getElementById("vote").innerHTML = current + 1;
  }

  function downVoteFunction() {
    var current = parseInt(document.getElementById("vote").innerHTML);
    document.getElementById("vote").innerHTML = current>0 ? current - 1 : 0;
  }
</script>

<p>how do you vote?</p>
<button class="downVote" onClick="downVoteFunction()">></button>
<span id="vote">0</span>
<button class="upVote" onClick="upVoteFunction()">></button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Explanation : I have a added a function to increase/decrease the vote count depending on the parameter passed. That function is called from both up vote & down vote buttons (plus one vote from up vote button & minus one vote from down vote button). If you down want to have negative votes, you can add a check inside the function to make the vote `0` when the votes goes down to zero. Like this

```
vote = vote < 0 ? 0 : vote;
```

Try this.

```js
var vote = 0;
const voteFun =(val) => {
  vote = vote + val;
  vote = vote < 0 ? 0 : vote; //If you want vote not to go below zero
  document.getElementById('voteDisplay').innerHTML = vote;
}
```

```css
.upVote, .downVote{
            cursor:pointer;
            background-color: white;
            border: none;
}

.downVote {
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
        .upVote {
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            padding-bottom: -50;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<p>how do you vote?</p>
    <button onclick="voteFun(-1)" class="downVote">></button>
    <span id="voteDisplay">0</span>
    <button onclick="voteFun(1)" class="upVote">></button>
```

Comment: This allows the vote count to go negative… otherwise a decent approach, but without an explanation to the OP and future readers it's not what I would consider a "good answer" for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @StephenP The OP didn't ask for the number _not_ to go negative.

Comment: @Noah - True. I guess it depends on the purpose of the votes. I still think there are no good answers here yet because there are _no_ explanations, so not up- or down-voting any of them.

Comment: @StephenP I understand.

Comment: @StephenP thanks for your feedback I have added an explanation & a check for avoiding negative votes